# Cannot install YOURLS (PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in config.php on line 66)

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, yourls

I'm trying to install YOURLS but whenever I go to the admin page I get this error:

Anyway, can someone help me?

The config.php file I have is the following:

```
<?php
/* This is a sample config file.
* Edit this file with your own settings and save it as "config.php"
*/

/*
** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host
*/

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'YOURLS_DB_USER', 'MySQLUsername' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'YOURLS_DB_PASS', 'MySQLPassword' );

/** The name of the database for YOURLS */
define( 'YOURLS_DB_NAME', 'MySQLDatabase' );

/** MySQL hostname.
 ** If using a non standard port, specify it like 'hostname:port', eg. 'localhost:9999' or '127.0.0.1:666' */
define( 'YOURLS_DB_HOST', 'MySQLHost' );

/** MySQL tables prefix */
define( 'YOURLS_DB_PREFIX', 'yourls_' );

/*
 ** Site options
 */

/** YOURLS installation URL -- all lowercase and with no trailing slash.
 ** If you define it to "http://example.com", don't use "http://www.example.com" in your browser (and vice-versa) */
define( 'YOURLS_SITE', 'http://example.com' );

/** Timezone GMT offset */
define( 'YOURLS_HOURS_OFFSET', 0 ); 

/** YOURLS language or "locale".
 ** Change this setting to "localize" YOURLS (use a translation instead of the default English). A corresponding .mo file
 ** must be installed in the user/language directory.
 ** See http://yourls.org/translations for more information */
define( 'YOURLS_LANG', '' ); 

/** Allow multiple short URLs for a same long URL
 ** Set to true to have only one pair of shortURL/longURL (default YOURLS behavior)
 ** Set to false to allow multiple short URLs pointing to the same long URL (bit.ly behavior) */
define( 'YOURLS_UNIQUE_URLS', true );

/** Private means the Admin area will be protected with login/pass as defined below.
 ** Set to false for public usage (eg on a restricted intranet or for test setups)
 ** Read http://yourls.org/privatepublic for more details if you're unsure */
define( 'YOURLS_PRIVATE', true );

/** A random secret hash used to encrypt cookies. You don't have to remember it, make it long and complicated. Hint: copy from http://yourls.org/cookie **/
define( 'YOURLS_COOKIEKEY', 'ogjorgjorgjOJFIJFEIJfejfejirporegohi' );

/** Username(s) and password(s) allowed to access the site. Passwords either in plain text or as encrypted hashes
 ** YOURLS will auto encrypt plain text passwords in this file
 ** Read http://yourls.org/userpassword for more information */
$yourls_user_passwords = array(
    'MyUsername' => 'MyPassword',

/** Debug mode to output some internal information

 ** Default is false for live site. Enable when coding or before submitting a new issue */

define( 'YOURLS_DEBUG', false );

/*
 ** URL Shortening settings
 */

/** URL shortening method: 36 or 62 */
define( 'YOURLS_URL_CONVERT', 62 );
/*
 * 36: generates all lowercase keywords (ie: 13jkm)
 * 62: generates mixed case keywords (ie: 13jKm or 13JKm)
 * Stick to one setting. It's best not to change after you've started creating links.
 */

/** 
* Reserved keywords (so that generated URLs won't match them)
* Define here negative, unwanted or potentially misleading keywords.
*/
$yourls_reserved_URL = array(
    'blocked', 'blocked2', 'blocked3', 'blocked4', 'blocked5', 'blocked6', 'b7', 'b8',
);

/*
 ** Personal settings would go after here.
 */
```

MySQL information and passwords shown are concealed (Keep that in mind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is not getting closed.

Go to line 59:

Change

```
$yourls_user_passwords = array(
    'MyUsername' => 'MyPassword',
```

To:

```
$yourls_user_passwords = array(
    'MyUsername' => 'MyPassword',
);
```

Hope it works for you.